# Is it possible to access the constructor of the base class from the inherited class object?

Tags: c++, class, object, initialization

So I'm wondering if it is actually possible to access the constructor of the base class from the inherited classes object? Something like:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int i)
    {
        id = i;
    }
protected:
    int id;
};

class Bar: public Foo
{
public:
    void barFunc()
    {
        if (id>0)
        {
            std::cout << "Bar stuff" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Other Bar stuff" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo fooObj(7);
    Bar b; //is it possible to access 'id' in Bar whilst initializing 'id' in Foo?
    b.barFunc();
}
```

If I just run barFunc() object b will act as if 'id' hasn't been initialized.

Have an assignment to do and I'm unsure how to work with the code they've given me.
Thanks! :)

Comment: Why not try to compile the code. You're missing a constructor in `Bar` (add it or inherit it), and use of in declaration of `b`. You'll have to fix that.

Comment: Does this compile actually? And yes, it's possible, just use the member initializer list with `Bar`s constructor.

Comment: Thanks, yes I was missing the constructor for Bar my apologies, yes it worked but I left the constructor empty and had if id wasn't initialized wasn't initialized, it would cout "id was not initialized". This is a was just a quick water down of what I was trying to articulate is just a few lines. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first create constructor matching base class:

```
Bar(int i) : Foo(i) { }
```

then

```
Bar b(1);
b.barFunc();
```

and no need of

```
Foo fooObj(7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `id` is `protected` you can access it in `Bar`.